# Set Power BI Embedded key through ARM template

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded, azure-rm-template

Is there any way to set Power BI Access Keys through an ARM template? When I created the resource, two access keys were generated but not specified in the ARM template. Can I have this resource use the same key as a previously made Power BI workspace collection?

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections",
            "sku": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "tags": { "displayName": "Power BI" },
            "name": "[parameters('powerBIname')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-29",
            "location": "eastus2",
            //"keys": [
            //    {
            //        "keyName": "Key 1",
            //        "value": "xxxx"
            //    },
            //    {
            //        "keyName": "Key 2",
            //        "value": "yyyy"
            //    }
            //]
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, keys are generated by Azure. You cannot set them, but you can get the keys using the `ListKeys` function and output them to use further.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Does this mean that if I ever need to remake the resource, there'll be entirely new keys? If so, is this a hassle for people using it or relatively easy to work around. Sorry, I don't know a lot about power BI

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. work around - update your connection string.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. The question was just if each time the resource was created they'd have to update their connection strings, and I guess it is.

Comment: yeah, you can use `ListKeys` to get the keys and update connection strings